# Optimize Neo4j Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What I'm doing is to get all *profiles** who has a specific directed relation to a *users profile** and if those have an *alternate profile** get those in case the *users alternate profile** has a relation to it. I also need the direction of the relations.

My problem is, with about 10000 nodes it takes about 5 seconds to get data.
I have auto index on nodes and relationships.

This is how my nodes are related:

> User-[:profile]->ProfileA-[:related]->ProfileB<-[?:me]->ProfileB2<-[?:related]-ProfileA2<-[:profile]-User

My query looks like this:

```
START User=node({source}) 
MATCH User-[:profile]->ProfileA-[rel:related]->ProfileB 
WHERE User-->ProfileA-->ProfileB 
WITH ProfileA, rel, ProfileB 
MATCH ProfileB<-[?:me]->ProfileB2<-[relB?:related]-ProfileA2<-[:profile]-User 
WHERE relB IS NULL OR User-->ProfileA-->ProfileB<-->ProfileB2<--ProfileA2<--User
RETURN ProfileB, COLLECT(ProfileB2), rel, relB
LIMIT 25
```

Any idea how I can optimize the query?

---

- <sub>profiles: ProfileB</sub>
- <sub>users profile: ProfileA</sub>
- <sub>alternate profile: ProfileB2</sub>
- <sub>users alternate profile: ProfileA2</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
START User=node({source}) 
MATCH User-[:profile]->ProfileA-[rel:related]->ProfileB<-[?:me]->ProfileB2-[relB?:related]-ProfileA2
WHERE relB IS NULL OR User-[:profile]->ProfileA2
RETURN ProfileB, COLLECT(ProfileB2), rel, relB
LIMIT 25
```

The `ProfileA2<-[:profile]-User` seemed to produce an endless loop.

Recommendations are still welcome.

Answer (score 6):

You're using `WHERE` clauses where you don't need to. Let's look at the first one for example:

```
WHERE User-->ProfileA-->ProfileB
```

This clause says "restrict the results only to users that have a relationship to a ProfileA which itself has a relationship to a ProfileB". However, that is already guaranteed to be true by your match clause. You're wasting CPU cycles re-verifying something that is already true.

```
WITH ProfileA, rel, ProfileB
```

You aren't doing any sort of aggregation, calculation or reassignment, so there is no need for this `WITH` clause. You can continue on without it.

```
WHERE relB IS NULL OR User-->ProfileA-->ProfileB<-->ProfileB2<--ProfileA2<--User
```

Again, you're not getting any value out of this `WHERE` clause. This one says "restrict the results to paths where a relB wasn't found OR where one was found with the following path..." and then you list the exact same path that was in your `MATCH`.

So, remove all those extraneous clauses and you get this:

```
START User=node({source}) 
MATCH User-[:profile]->ProfileA-[rel:related]->ProfileB<-[?:me]->ProfileB2<-[relB?:related]-ProfileA2<-[:profile]-User 
RETURN ProfileB, COLLECT(ProfileB2), rel, relB
LIMIT 25
```

Try that and see if the performance is any better. If it's not enough then you may need to add more information to your question -- for my own part, I don't fully understand what your relationships actually *mean* (for example, what is the "me" relationship? what does it symbolize?)

Comment: The problem with your query is that I get dublicates. There must only be one hop between each node, and as I understand it Neo4j is greedy, unless you specify [:profile*..1] but that wont work with optional relationships, which is why I need WHERE.

Comment: The [:me] relationship symbolize your Twitter profile linked to your GitHub profile.

Comment: Here's an example: http://console.neo4j.org/r/3hjktv made by `CREATE (User), (UserProfileA), (UserProfileB), (ProfileA), (ProfileB),
User-[:profile]->UserProfileA-[:follow]->ProfileA-[:me]->ProfileB,
ProfileA-[:follow]->UserProfileA,
User-[:profile]->UserProfileB-[:follow]->ProfileB-[:me]->ProfileA,
ProfileB-[:follow]->UserProfileB;`

Comment: @webjay I'm not sure what you mean by greedy in your first comment. It won't traverse more than one depth unless you specify `:profile*` or some variation of a variable length path.

Comment: I thought Neo4j was greedy as the manual [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#match-variable-length-relationships) states that _minHops and maxHops are optional and default to 1 and infinity respectively_ but I guess that's only if * is used.