# Error: org.neo4j.cypher.ProfilerStatisticsNotReadyException: This result has not been materialised yet

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to [optimize a Cypher query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146883/optimize-neo4j-cypher-query), but then [an example I made](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=3hjktv) gives me:

> Error: org.neo4j.cypher.ProfilerStatisticsNotReadyException: This result has not been materialised yet. Iterate over it to get profiler stats.

Any idea what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without the `limit` clause at the end. The profiling stuff is brand new--looks like you may have found a bug there, if you want to report it on github: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues. Not sure if it's console or Cypher.

Comment: The issue: [Cypher: Profile throws exception on queries with LIMIT](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/578).